# Promise - wrapping error during deferred.reject

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm trying to create a deferred wrapper using `q.js` such that I can wrap errors (strings) in a custom error class before they're passed back by the promise in `then()` or `fail()`. This is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
var getDeferred = function() {

    var deferred = q.defer();

    var reject = deferred.reject;
    deferred.reject = function(error) {

        if (!(error instanceof MyErrorClass))
            error = new MyErrorClass(error)

        return reject.apply(deferred, arguments);
    }

    return deferred;
}
```

So the idea is that the user would do something like

```
var deferred = getDeferred();

deferred.promise.fail(function(err) {
    // err should now be instance of MyErrorClass and NOT a string
})

deferred.reject('A string error')
```

And expect to get `MyErrorClass` in the `fail()` handler, rather than the string passed to `deferred.reject`.

The above code works, but it's hardly ideal -- I know I shouldn't be monkey-patching deferred.reject. But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well you should not be using deferreds in general at all. Writing manual code to promisify callback APIs is a huge waste of code. It is unfortunate that Q.nbind doesn't auto-wrap string errors but you can always write your own implementation that does.

Comment: @Esailija -- I just wanted to thank you for this comment, it's clarified my understanding of promises a lot. Originally I thought creating a deferred was the canonical way to create a new promise. I've been playing around with q.js and things are so much more straightforward now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's prettier / more promise oriented like this :

```
var getDeferred = function() {

    var deferred = q.defer();

    deferred.promise = deferred.promise.then(null, function(error) {
        if (!(error instanceof MyErrorClass))
            error = new MyErrorClass(error)

        throw error
    }

    return deferred;
}
```

This way you just attach an error handler which will mutate any non `MyErrorClass` errors. It seems like an odd use case in general though...

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. I know it's an odd use case, it's one of those cases of convincing people to move to promises on an existing codebase, while supporting some of the same things the current callback-soup does.

Answer (score 0):

Simply map over the fail case with `then`:

```
actualPromise.then(null, function(error) {
    if (!(error instanceof MyErrorClass))
        error = new MyErrorClass(error)
    throw error;
})
.fail(function(err) {
    // err is now an instance of MyErrorClass and NOT a string
});
```

If you need a wrapper functionality, use a function that takes the `actualPromise` and calls `then` with the above code on it.